# How to convert List<char> to List<string> in c#?

Tags: c#, list, split

I have text. for example `string text = "COMPUTER"`
And I want to split it into characters,  to keep every character as string.
If there were any delimiter I can use `text.Split(delimiter)`.
But there is not any delimiter, I convert it to **char array** with
**`text.ToCharArray().toList()`**.
And after that I get `List<char>`. But I need `List<string>`.
So How can I convert `List<char>` to `List<string>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just iterate over the collection of characters, and convert each to a string:

```
var result = input.ToCharArray().Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Or shorter (and more efficient, since we're not creating an extra array in between):

```
var result = input.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   var result = input.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Ripple: because the answer has been edited since (but still within the initial "historyless" time window). The original answer had nothing to do with the question

Comment: thank you @Ripple and knittl for being fair , I was mistaken in getting the question in hurry and I'm sorry for that

Comment: @Ripple: I cannot remove the upvote, because the edit does not show up as edit. Upvotes can only be removed after a (real) edit was made.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
string text = "COMPUTER"
var listOfChars = text.Select(x=>new String(new char[]{x})).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that a `string` is internally already very close to an `char[]`

Approach without LINQ:

```
List<string> list = new List<string();
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    list.Add(s[i].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    string bla = "COMPUTER"; //Your String
    List<char> list = bla.ToCharArray().ToList(); //Your char list
    List<string> otherList = new List<string>(); //Your string list
    list.ForEach(c => otherList.Add(c.ToString())); //iterate through char-list convert every char to string and add it to your string list
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Key:

charList is your Character List

strList is your String List

Code:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
foreach(char x in charList)
{
    strList.Add(x.ToString());
}
```