# C#: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, list, type-conversion

I would like to do some kind of console framework and for that I need command and arguments for the command. Here is part of my code:

```
string str = "I do not know how to fix this problem";
List<string> substringList = str.Split().ToList();
List<string> allArgsExcept1st = str[1..^0].ToList();
```

The input is type `string`.
The third line throws an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<char>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'.

I am new to C# so I don't know what to think about this error and how to possibly fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27978563/how-to-convert-listchar-to-liststring-in-c

Comment: @Maddy that answer is not really useful yet.  Important context is missing and may change whether that answer is even relevant

Comment: @maccettura, completely agree but sorting jumping the gun in case the user find its informational

Comment: Fair enough! I just didnt want it to be marked as a dupe too early

Comment: Do you mean `var allArgsExcept1st = substringList.Skip(1);`? And why are you converting everything to a `List`?

Comment: As a side note, `1..^0` can be shortened to `1..`

Comment: Another aside; `string.Split()` does not parse command line arguments. Fortunately there are already [many packages that do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631410).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest edit:

```
string str = "I do not know how to fix this problem";
List<string> substringList = str.Split().ToList();
List<string> allArgsExcept1st = str[1..^0].ToList();
```

The problem you have is here:

```
str[1..^0].ToList()
```

When you are using the range/slice function (`[1..^0]`) on your `string` you are, in return, getting a `string`.  So calling `ToList()` on that `string` will give you a `List<char>` (since a `string` is *also* a `IEnumerable<char>`) but you are assigning it to a `List<string>`.

Its unclear what you are ultimately trying to do here, but to fix your problem you just need to change your last line to:

```
List<char> allArgsExcept1st = str[1..^0].ToList();
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect this conceals the error instead of fixing it.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yeah I can see that.  I took it as an opportunity to teach OP about strings being IEnumerable<char> at the implications of their slicing code.  OP hasnt given much detail so I cant really provide better feedback until they do.  However I still think my answer is actually a proper answer, and the OP's question still technically meets the criteria so idk